# How to create an AWS EC2 instance with aws2 cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an AWS Educate stater account. I want to create an instances via the AWS command line.

Command:

> aws2 ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0bba96c31d87e65d9 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name awskey --security-group-ids sg-1830914d --subnet-id subnet-a5d2def9 --region us-east-1 --placement AvailabilityZone=us-east-1d

This is the error I get:

> An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.`

I am new to AWS, your help would highly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to fix this? I also suggest changing your request type to `t3.micro`

Comment: I did it doesn't work. but I get another error message <code>when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: zyWnlpq-ebISW7Od4p............</code>

Comment: placement option would be json format.

Comment: Is there anything non-standard about your VPC? Like dedicated tenancy?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know anything else non-standard, but my VPC is default.

Comment: @KadeerAziz OK, it could be an issue specific to launching t2.micro in us-east-1d so try a different instance type and try a different AZ. PS when responding to comments on Stack Overflow, please reference the user's handle (like I did at the start of this comment) so that the person you are talking to is notified of your comment, otherwise there is a risk they will never see it.

Comment: @jarmod noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things you should check. First you should check that you have enough rights for your user to work with the ec2 section.

The next thing is that you should use the last version of the aws cli to prevent some problems.

Here is an example command how to run an instance from an AMI.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-903004f8 --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e
```

So your line looks pretty fine.

Actual version of the CLI is `1.16`. You use version 2 which is still in development. This could be the reason why you get some messages that the functions aren't supported at this moment. Perhaps you name is only `"aws2"`.

https://pypi.org/project/awscli/#history

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I run this command in my friend's computer that has 'aws' not 'aws2', we got the same error.

Comment: Then i would suggest you should check your access rights and if you have the correct key in you configuration. Your line looks correct. When there is something wrong you should get other error messages.

Comment: I can run commands as 'aws2 ec2 describe-instances'. If my credentials were not right, then I would be able to run commands like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your `~/.aws` configuration and credentials established ... this is a script I use to do an unattended quick EC2 instance (requires `bash` and `jq`):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "\nusage:\t$(basename $0) <EC2 resource base name>"
    echo -e "\tcreate minimum EC2 resources and free tier EC2 instance"
    echo -e "\nExample:\n\t$(basename $0) MYCORPAWS01\n"
    exit 2
fi
BASE_ID="$1"
GROUP_NAME="${BASE_ID}"
REGION=us-east-2
FREE_TIER_INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.micro

# create security group
GROUP_ID=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --region="${REGION}" --group-name "${GROUP_NAME}" --description "vanilla security group" | jq -r .GroupId)
if [ -z "${GROUP_ID}" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to create security group \"${GROUP_NAME}\""
    exit 1
else
    echo "INFO: create security group \"${GROUP_NAME}\" successful"
fi

# authorize SSH in group
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --region="${REGION}" --group-name "${GROUP_NAME}" --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 >/dev/null
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "WARN: failed to authorize ingress for security group \"${GROUP_NAME}\""
else
    echo "INFO: authorize security group ingress (port 22) successful"
fi

# create key pair
if [ ! -f "${BASE_ID}"-key.pem ]; then
    aws ec2 create-key-pair --region="${REGION}" --key-name "${BASE_ID}-key" --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > "${BASE_ID}"-key.pem
    if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "WARN: failed to create key pair \"${BASE_ID}-key\""
    else
        chmod 400 "${BASE_ID}"-key.pem
        echo "INFO: create key pair (with local private key \"${BASE_ID}-key.pem\") successful"
    fi
fi

# get free tier AMI
FREE_TIER_AMI=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.????????.?-x86_64-gp2" "Name=state,Values=available" --query "reverse(sort_by(Images, &Name))[:1].ImageId" --region us-west-2 --output text)
if [ -z "${FREE_TIER_AMI}" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to identify free tier AMI"
    exit 1
else
    echo "INFO: using free tier AMI \"${FREE_TIER_AMI}\" for instance"
fi

# create instance
INSTANCE_ID=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id "${FREE_TIER_AMI}" \
                                    --region="${REGION}" \
                                    --security-group-ids "${GROUP_ID}" \
                                    --instance-type "${FREE_TIER_INSTANCE_TYPE}" \
                                    --key-name "${BASE_ID}-key" |  jq -r '.Instances[].InstanceId')
if [ -z "${INSTANCE_ID}" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to create instance"
    exit 1
else
    echo "INFO: create instance successful (instance id \"${INSTANCE_ID}\")"
fi

# output instance info
echo "waiting for instance to become available ..."
aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids "${INSTANCE_ID}"

echo -e "\ninstance available:"
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "${INSTANCE_ID}" | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | {InstanceId: .InstanceId, PublicIpAddress: .PublicIpAddress, PublicDnsName: .PublicDnsName}'
INSTANCE_IP=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "${INSTANCE_ID}" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress')

RED='\033[0;31m'
MAGENTA='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
NOCOLOR='\033[0m'

echo -e "\ninitial SSH access:"
echo -e ${MAGENTA}
echo "ssh -i ${BASE_ID}-key.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new ec2-user@${INSTANCE_IP}"
echo -e ${NOCOLOR}
```

Usually takes about 5 minutes to complete; when it is done, it outputs the SSH command-line to let you connect to the instance.